# Control access to class

Tags: php

I am using a class and functions for a controller.
Consider the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/mvc/user/profile/1
```

The class is user and the function is profile.
What is the best technique for someone going to

```
http://localhost:8888/mvc/user/random
```

and getting redirected elsewhere if the function isn't present?
As I'm unsure about this, I don't know what extra information you may need?

Comment: htaccess is helpful for you.right?

Comment: you can use magic method to check if function is available and then use header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); to redirect him to 404 page.

Comment: Why *redirect* them? Wouldn't a 404 message be more logical?

Comment: this can help you buddy `http://www.htaccessredirect.net/`

Comment: Is that something like your own framework/library? Or some framework like Zend/CakePHP?

Comment: `header('Location: /another/url'); die()` -- redirect without 404 error, sometimes useful. With Location you should specify absolute, not relative paths, but to be honest I never found a browser or another webapp which cannot handle relative paths.

Comment: @Tom — Lynx will complain at the user as it performs error recovery on that.

Comment: @Quentin Haven't used Lynx for ages, but good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create htaccess with

```
//Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8888/mvc/user/profile/1
```

You will get more details about .htaccess [from here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use php itself ?

```
if(!function_exists($function)){
 return header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

You can also redirect with the header function. So you can also add more logic if needed without having to depend on .htaccess or som other mechanism.

Comment: OP is using methods, not functions.

Comment: Then you can use class_exists() and method_exists()

Answer (score 0):

Use the magical method `__call()` to handle arbitrary method calls.